# How to target android applications to a particular country?

Tags: android

I had developed an application and the app targets only to a specific country.

Is the selection of country in developer console is enough to target the specific country or do I have to do any other settings ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store filter are enough to restrict countries, it will not let the user download the app.

However if you want further configuration and implementation you can look for

`mcc` and `locale` of the device [`android:configChanges`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config)

Answer (score 1):

Developer console selections are basically play store filters. It is meant for the purpose of filtering your apps from countries.